# Array in Classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm still new to classes so here what i have done so far. In this program I have to prompt the user to input how many products and the prices and i have to display back again like this :

```
No     Product Code    Price
1         101          4.50
```

and calculate the average price.

my class have to hold up to 100 objects which I'm still not sure how o implement. Hope anyone can help me with this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Product{
private :
    int code;
    double price;

public :
    Product ();
    void setCode(int);
    void setPrice(double);

    int getCode();
    double getPrice();
};

Product :: Product()
{
    code = 0;
    price = 0;
}

void Product :: setCode(int c)
{
    code = c;
}

void Product :: setPrice(double p)
{
    price = p;
}

int Product :: getCode()
{
    return code;
}

double Product :: getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

int main(){

    const int size = 100;
    Product m[size];
    int procode;
    double proprice;
    int num;
    double sum= 0;

    cout << "How many products to enter? ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<num ;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the information of product #"<< (i+1)<<endl;

        int code;
        cout << "\tProduct Code: ";
        cin >> code;
        m[i].setCode( code );

        double price;
        cout << "\tPrice: ";
        cin >> price;
        m[i].setPrice( price );

        sum = sum + price;
    }

    ///output??
    cout <<"No"<<"   "<<"Product Code"<<"   "<<"Price" <<endl;


    cout<<"   "<<m[i].getCode()<<"   "<<m[i].getPrice()<<endl;

    cout<<"Average: " << sum/num << endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: i haven't learn using vector... any other options?

Comment: Practicing with simple arrays is good at first but you should really learn to use std::vector and std::array, it will simplify your code, prevent hard-to-find bugs and most of all - it's the C++ way to do it. Many people start learning C++ by using C-features like `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function main can be written the following way

```
int main()
{
    const size_t MAX_ITEMS = 100;
    Product m[MAX_ITEMS];
    size_t num;

    cout << "How many products to enter? ";
    cin  >> num;

    if ( MAX_ITEMS < num ) num = MAX_ITEMS;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the information of product #" << (i+1) << endl;

        int code;
        cout << "\tProduct Code: ";
        cin >> code;
        m[i].setCode( code );

        double price;
        cout < "\tPrice: ";
        cin >> price;
        m[i].setPrice( price );
    }

    // here can be the code for output data

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do i need to create another array for output?

Comment: @user3544721 You have to use the same array and the number num to output the array. The control statement of the loop will be the same as for entering data.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<num ;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the information of product #"<< (i+1)<<endl;
        cout << "Product Code:";
        cin >> procode;
        m[i].setCode(procode);
        cout < "\nPrice:";
        cin >> proprice;
        m[i].setPrice(proprice);
    }
```

This will set required number of objects.

Access as

```
  cout<<m[index].getCode()<<m[index].getPrice();
```

Comment: how should i declare the array?

Comment: ouh yes tx. but I'm having trouble accessing it.

Comment: @user3544721 still not clear what you are asking. My code works on my local machine

Comment: The loop condition is incomplete.  It should be `for(int i=0; i<num && i<size ;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean dynamic allocation?
If you want to have variable amount of Products specified by user, you must create the array dynamically after you know `num`.
For example:

```
int main() {

    Product * m;
    int num;

    cout << "How many products to enter? ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    m = new Product[num];

    for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        // something with the array
    }

    delete [] m;

    return 0;

}
```